# How do I set the tab order in a form in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, forms

I've created an Excel input form with 4 textboxes that line up on top of each other.  I can't figure out how to set the tab order.  In the properties section for the controls the only thing close to 'tab' is 'AutoTab' and 'TabKeyBehavior', both of which are boolean values, true and false.

How do you set the tab order for form controls in Excel?

Comment: rightclick the userform and click the last option "Tab Order". You'll get a Window where you can change the order pretty easy ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are after is called `TabIndex`. It shows in the properties when the control is selected. The first field has TabIndex 0.

[image]